# connect-mongo error while building with tsc: Cannot find module 'mongoose'

Tags: typescript, connect-mongo

I'm using `connect-mongo` to store sessions in a typescript project directly with the mongodb driver, without using moongose.
I'm initializing it with `clientPromise` as following:

```js
const store = new MongoStore({
    clientPromise: getMongoPromise(),
    collection: config.get('sessionCollection'),
    touchAfter: 24 * 3600,
    ttl: Number(config.get('sessionDuration')) * 24 * 3600,
});
```

When I run my app in dev mode (with `ts-node --transpile-only src/start.ts`) everything works fine, but when I try to compile it using `tsc` it gives me this error:

```sh
$ tsc
node_modules/connect-mongo/src/types.d.ts(11,27): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'mongoose'.
error Command failed with exit code 2.
```

I'm not using `moongose` in my app so I don't want to install it just to silence this error.
Is there another way to fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I found it, I was missing the `@types/connect-mongo` dev package. I trusted VSCode that didn't warn me about missing types but I was wrong.

After installing it the compilation now runs fine:

```
yarn add -D @types/connect-mongo
```

Answer (score 0):

`mongoose` must be installed in production dependencies `npm i --save mongoose` for typescript

And not in devDependencies `npm i --save-dev mongoose`.